# Not able to access Variable inside JSX

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the variable StudentId inside JSX of the same component but I'm getting the error as "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
What am I doing wrong here? PS I'm new to react. Also,I'm getting the value of StudentId in console. Thank You in advance.

`

```
export default function StudentDetail() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const StudentId = router.query.StudentID;
  console.log(StudentId);
  const data = [
    {
      name: "Abc",
      contact: "9909990990",
      
    },
    {
      name: "Def",
      contact: "8880808008",
    },
    {
      name: "ghi",
      contact: "7700700077",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <TableList
        name={data[StudentId].name}
        contact={data[StudentId].contact}
      />
    </div>
  );
}`
```

Comment: What is the value of `StudentId`? You will only get an error if the value of `StudentId` is less then 0 or greater than 2.

Comment: `data[StudentId]` is an array, you cannot directly access the value of array, you might need to do something like `data[StudentId][0].name`

Comment: @Yousaf I'm using it in next js as a dynamic page. In the above example, I am checking for  the value of StudentId = 1.

Comment: @CodeNinja `StudentId` in `data[StudentId]` is the index.

Comment: @CodeNinja Yes. `StudentId`  is the index.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing out. I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens during initial rendering, provide some validation. I assume `StudentId` is array index like `0`, `1` etc.

```
  {StudentId >= 0 && <TableList
    name={data[StudentId].name}
    contact={data[StudentId].contact}
  />}
```